# Eclipse e4 go [navigate] method declaration in editor (part)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I use ast parser to parse whole java workspace. At the end of parsing, I have method declaration list (these methods are problematic for my project). And this list elements are added to tableviewer in my own view like problems view.(Attention : I don't want to add this list to problems view) Every method declaration has information such as path,location,line number so I have everything to navigate method declaration. When the user double click to list element , he will go to declaration.

EXAMPLE :

```
@Inject
EPartService partService;


MPart part = partService.findPart("editor id");  // HOW DO I FIND METHOD PAGE

partService.showPart(part, PartState.ACTIVATE);  // IF I OPEN JAVA FILE IN EDITOR HOW DO I GO TO METHOD LİNE IN THIS PART
```

But I don't know how to make in eclipse e4. Please give me a advise.

Answer (score 0):

A quick-and-easy approach is to use JDT's `JavaUI.openInEditor()`: that will allow you to open on a specific method within a class.  It will open an editor if required, and will return the editor.

Since you have a line number, and you'll have a text editor from the call to `JavaUI`, you can then check if it's an `ITextEditor` and, if so, then use `ITextEditor.selectAndReveal()`.  This takes an offset into the editor content string, so you'll have to map your line number to the offset using the editor's underlying `Document`.  That can usually be obtained from the editor's `DocumentProvider`.  Something like: `editor.getDocumentProvider().getDocument(editor.getEditorInput())`.